# Custom directives not resolving over SSL Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please look at this page

(https)[url]/cart

and compare with

(http)[url]/cart

You will notice the console errors on the secure version and there are no console errors in the insecure version. I am using Angular custom directives they are not resolving over the secure protocol. My assumption would be there is a resource which is being blocked?? However I cannot find this resource... any ideas?

I have also tested this locally with a self signed certificate and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this partial is entirely different between your http and https server:
/partials/bonuses.html

The https version of bonuses is just a page with a script that sets the window.location to the non-https version. As far as I know, you cannot put an html tag as a directive's template, and that's why angular is throwing up errors. It wouldn't make any sense to do that anyway.

You need to make sure that the https server serves the full bonuses.html partial, and not just a redirect to http